# Monitoring a java request

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Is there a way to identify if the process is running currently and to define how long it has been running when it is triggered?

Say for instance, I make a web service/ web app call to a method named `getFirstName()` which has a call to the database to retrieve the names. Just before this I have a `AOP` advise methodinterceptor which will intercept the method `getFirstName()`. Now in the interceptor I will note the start time of this request and then proceed to the actual method, now i need to trigger a mail to the user if the request has been running for a long time.so How do I keep track of this request timing?
I don't want to use any thread to avoid the complexity, is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Who do you want to send out the email about the request taking too long?

Comment: One way or another you're going to have to use an another thread(or an external actor) to do something for you otherwise you'll be blocking until the `getFirstName()` method returns.

Comment: Just an informational mail to the dba/monitoring team saying that this request is taking longer than expected. BTW, I will have a threshold value defined in my app.

Comment: I don't get your question. What is so wrong with your AOP suggestion? BTW. you know things like [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/)?

Comment: Th problem with the AOP is that, it shows me that the query has run for a long time only afer the method execution is done. Whereas I need something like peter.petrov is suggesting but have a few quetions as commented below..

Comment: OK got it. It's crucial that dba/monitoring team gets its message in real time.

Answer (score 3):

You can organize it yourself. In getFirstName() you 
have some sequence of operations/actions being done.

Either

1)
The getFirstName() has to somehow poll its own status (because 
you said you don't want another process/thread to monitor it). But this
sounds weird and more difficult to do. Also, it has this problem that if
getFirstName() calls some long-running operation, then the polling will
not work (as getFirstName() is busy with something else currently).

or

2)
Another process/thread can check the status of the getFirstName() processes.
If the status is not DONE and some decent amount of time has elapsed,
it will send out an email. The responsibility of the getFirstName()
is to just set its status to DONE, once it is done and to STARTED
once it has started. Also, each getFirstName() call probably needs to have
some unique ID. That's basically it.

Comment: Thanks, am talking about 500-1000 requests a day as it will be a widely used service. Do you think if it will be an optimal solution to have another thread in parallel to each triggered process?

Comment: @Faz No, no. You need just one monitor thread. Not one thread per getFirstName() call but one single monitor thread which will always run on the background. It will just query some DB table e.g. and send out emails. The getFirstName() calls/processes will report their progresses into that table. That's all, quite simple. And 500-1000 calls per day is not that much btw ;)

Comment: okie got that point. I already have a table reporting the status of the query i think am good there .But really not sure as to how I will spawn a thread in my AOP METHOD. Am quite new to this thread concept, could you please help me with an example?

Comment: @Faz Just start a new thread where your program starts, or if it's an app running in some framework, usually the framework notifies you that your app is deployed/started. At that place, start a new thread which will do the monitoring.

Comment: am using the spring framework, so where do you think will be the optimal place to have it started. And since it will be parallel requests thats been triggered, how can we make sure that this SINGLE thread cna handle these individual requests separately? One another point I would like to emphasis here is that this will be made availale in a cluster environment, so having each JVM will spawn a single thread each.. are we good there?

Comment: Say for instance, if i ahve requests triggered by 2  different users, which calls the same mthod. How will this single thread make sure that it reports the respctive stats via the email? One might have ran fine and other took a bit longer. ?

Comment: @Faz You can identify them by userID/callID. You need to have some way to identify the different calls. Even 1 single user can make 2 different calls - one takes long, the other one runs in time. So each call needs to have a unique callID and it needs to be associated with the user who made this call i.e. to its userID. But you need to have all this no matter if you use that approach with the monitoring thread (which I suggested) or some other approach.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45517/discussion-between-faz-and-peter-petrov)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz to fire an evente every 10 seconds or so. 
There you will have to check in a map or something your processes and when they started.
Make the calculation ( now() - startTime()) and send the mail if you have to.